# Change in string initialization induces UB

Tags: c++

Edit: Please refer to this abbreviated version of the question:

---

Why does the definition

```
char word[2];
word[0]='a';
word[1]='b';
```

introduce UB?

---

Summary: I have written code which renders the alphabetic portion of a string. When applied to a single string, it seems to work without issue. When used element-wise on a string vector using a for loop, however, it suffers from UB. There is an (apparent) workaround: define the output string using an initialization constructor, i.e.:

```
std::string output(2,'A');
```

instead of using the familiar:

```
char output[2];
```

Below is a (rather) simplified reproducible example wherein the outputs of two similar functions are compared. return_alpha uses the former initialization and return_alpha2 the latter. distribute_ra applies either return_alpha or return_alpha2 depending on modal input.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

std::string return_alpha(std::string s){
    int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if (std::isalpha(s[i])){
            count++;
        }
    }
    //char output[count];
    std::string output(count,'A');
    int idx=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if (std::isalpha(s[i])){
            output[idx]=s[i];
            idx++;
        }
    }
    return output;
}

std::string return_alpha2(std::string s, int mode){
    int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if (std::isalpha(s[i])){
            count++;
        }
    }

    char output[count+1];
    //std::string output(count,'A');
    int idx=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if (std::isalpha(s[i])){
            output[idx]=s[i];
            idx++;
        }
    }
    output[count]='\0';
    return output;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<std::string> distribute_ra(std::vector<std::string> s2,int s2len, int mode){
    std::vector<std::string> output(s2len);
    if (mode==0){
        for (int i = 0; i < s2len; i++) {
            
            output[i] = return_alpha(s2[i]);
        }
    }else{
        for (int i = 0; i < s2len; i++) {
            
            output[i] = return_alpha2(s2[i]);
        }
    }
    
    return output;
}

/*** R
distribute_ra(c("bobby10","bob","bob"),3,0)
distribute_ra(c("bobby10","bob","bob"),3,1)
*/
```

Evaluating the last bit yields:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('playground.cpp')

> distribute_ra(c("bobby10","bob1","bob"),3,0)
[1] "bobby" "bob"   "bob"  

> distribute_ra(c("bobby10","bob1","bob"),3,1)
[1] "bobby" "bobb" "bobb"
```

The expected output is

```
> distribute_ra(c("bobby10","bob1","bob"),3,0)
[1] "bobby" "bob"   "bob"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221215/discussion-on-question-by-josh-purtell-change-in-string-initialization-induces-u).

Answer (score 0):

C-style strings require termina. The definition should be as such:

```
char word[3];
word[0]='a';
word[1]='b';
word[2]='\0';
```

credit: @user253751